# How to prevent Labels on bottom of window from disappearing when resizing?

Tags: wpf, xaml

Basically I have a window is that `SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"` and I have a Label positioned on the bottom. When resizing the window the label disappears. Unless I make the window a lot bigger.

I have the following XAML code:

```
<Window x:Class="DateKeeper.View.Test"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DateKeeper.View"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Test" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"
        >
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Label x:Name="label" Content="Label" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" FontSize="36"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" Grid.Column="1" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Grid.Row="1" FontSize="36"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And here are the pictures:

Before Resizing

[image: Before resizing]

After resizing

[image: After resizing]

Comment: Be consistent in the the way you lay out properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SizeToWidthAndHeight` sets the window's *initial* size. It doesn't prevent the user from resizing the window.

`ResizeMode="NoResize"` will prevent all resizing. If you want to set a minimum size and allow the window to be sized larger than that, you can't do that in pure XAML.

However, you can use that initial size as a minimum width and height with some simple code in a loaded handler, like so:

```
<Window 
    x:Class="DateKeeper.View.Test"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DateKeeper.View"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Test" 
    SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"
    Loaded="Window_Loaded"
    >
```

Test.xaml.cs (or whatever you call the codebehind for the above Window):

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MinWidth = ActualWidth;
    MinHeight = ActualHeight;
}
```

You could also write an attached property that would do the same thing.

### Update

This pure-XAML approach with `Mode=OneTime` seems promising:

```
<Window
    ...
    SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"
    MinHeight="{Binding ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Mode=OneTime, PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}"
    MinWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Mode=OneTime}"
    ...
```

...but in trace output, we see that it gets the values of `ActualHeight` and `ActualWidth` very early on, before the window is sized to its content, perhaps before then actual UI window object is even created -- at a point when the actual width and height are both reported as zero.

Comment: Thanks, but my question was how can I put a label at the bottom of my form and it should not disappear when the form is resized. I do want to allow resize.

Comment: Yes, I misunderstood. Now I get it. I wrote the question a long time ago, before I understood how Grids work. Sorry. I did upvote but cannot reaccept. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You have 50% now

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Label x:Name="label" Content="Label"  FontSize="36" 
                Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" Text="TextBlock" FontSize="36"  
                Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to create, but three things:

1. The elements are losing visibility because they are going off of the screen because they are running out of room
2. Your layout puts both text elements in the second row of the Grid

   a. The elements will only have 50% of the available height to render

   b. FontSize and Margins/Padding will further offset this
3. You have two different text element types (Label and TextBlock)

   a. Both have different Margin/Padding values

   b. The different layout values will result in different levels of visibility

If you don't want the elements to lose visibility, you need to set a minimum size of the Window (e.g. 325x150).

Comment: Thanks. My problem is that at first everything displays the way I want it to, but when I resize the window, Labels that are on the bottom disappear. This happens even if I'm making window bigger. All my paddings and margins are set to 0. This is just minimal program to reproduce my problem.

Comment: The templates for Label and TextBlock are different. Label, for example doesn't even have the LineHeight property (as TextBlock does). This affects the layout. I would suggest that you find the layout that you like, place the layout inside a Border, set the Border to HorizontalAlignment/VerticalAlignment=Center, and set Window.MinHeight/MaxHeight to provide the space needed to properly render your content.